# How to make countif function in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, countif

I am trying to use COUNTIF function to calculate:

1. Match column values with tasks listed (A:A)
2. Count if tasks listed (A:A) falls with period designated during dated completed (i.e. 01/01/2023 to 31/01/2023) only if another column-Row(C:C) has specific text "Completed"
3. if (C:C) does not contain text "Completed" count (D:D) for task completed

I have multiple sheets. I am unable figure out the formula:

```
=COUNTIFS(Master_Sheet!$F:$F, iden,
          Master_Sheet!$M:$M, ">="&H1,
          Master_Sheet!$M:$M, "<="&H2)
```

- F:F = tasks
- iden = Tasks listed
- M:M date completed
- H1 H2 - Between dates

Comment: "*You are unable to figure out the formula*", does that mean that the formula is not working? For which values do you get wrong results? And what are the results you do expect? ...?

Comment: Why do you state that you need to test columns A:A, C:C and D:D when your function shows columns F:F and M:M ?

Comment: Apart from the above I'm puzzled by what you mean with *"I have multiple sheets."*